# python bs4 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, bs4

Пытаюсь парсить все названия и получаю ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
почему то он не находит не каких тегов и не кидает мне
[image: скрин div и a]

пожалуйста помогите хочу парсить названия товаров)
а через selenium он несколько товаров передает

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 6 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4324.96 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
mvideo_requests =requests.get('https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914', headers = headers)

mvideo_soup = BeautifulSoup(mvideo_requests.text,'html.parser')

paginator = mvideo_soup.find("div", {'class': 'product-title product-title--grid'})
name = paginator.find_all('a')
print(name)
print(mvideo_requests)
```

Comment: В `paginator` у вас None, значит `mvideo_soup.find` ничего не нашел. Проверьте, что в `mvideo_requests.text` нужные теги есть

Comment: @gil9red когда я именно вывожу mvideo_requests.text, то он мне кидает в html формате, то что доступ запрещен, как я могу обойти?

Comment: @gil9red   13.043 13.043 0 004.896 4.886.941.941 0 001.13-.152l.96-.96a.573.573 0 01.603-.125 10.69 10.69 0 002.335.581c.28.04.492.289.484.601v2.267a.571.571 0 01-.625.574 14.047 14.047 0 01-6.107-2.173 13.818 13.818 0 01-4.26-4.249 14.003 14.003 0 01-2.183-6.146.575.575 0 01.572-.607z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="nonzero"/></symbol><symbol fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="call_shop" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8.011 3a2.61 2.61 0 012.61 2.25c.092.696.263 1.38.508 2.035.359.952.13 2.027-.592 2.754l-.463.463a11.86 115.164-5.756-

Comment: @gil9red вот что он мне кинул

Comment: То, что в комментарии, это кусок svg. Сохраните страницу в файл и посмотрите через редактор. Возможно, то, что вы пытаетесь получить на странице нет, т.к. оно подгружается через javascript

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, походу так и есть буду искать как получить название через js

Comment: Я уже просмотрел, и правда. Элементы прогружаються через Js так что лучший выход использовать selenium.В ответе напишу рабочий код уже.

Comment: Попробуй вариант из этого вопроса. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745192/13265825 Ответ от NBlack

Comment: @ІванШнір если через ссылку которую я указывал не все товары передавать будут, максимум 7 товаров, не знаю почему так ,ну я поменял ссылку для каждого определенного товара тут получилось вывести все и через selenium работает и через bs4 https://www.mvideo.ru/promo/apple-iphone-12

Comment: @vladrunk попробовал ну он все ровно не правильно находит, как на примере попробовал и вот что он вывел print(mvideo_soup.find_all('title')) [<title> Ð.ÐÐ¸Ð´ÐµÐ¾ - Ð¸Ð½ÑÐµÑÐ½ÐµÑ-Ð¼Ð°Ð³Ð°Ð·Ð¸Ð½ ÑÐ¸Ñ
                                                        ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¸ Ð±ÑÑÐ¾Ð²Ð¾Ð¹ ÑÐµÑ
Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ¸ Ð¸ ÑÐ»ÐµÐºÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ¸, Ð½Ð¸Ð·ÐºÐ¸Ðµ ÑÐµÐ½Ñ, Ð±Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐ¾Ð¹ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð³, Ð¾ÑÐ·ÑÐ²Ñ. </title>]